# Qt: DB connection won't open

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I am trying to get a cookie out of my cookie-db of firefox. However, for some reason the database won't open.

```
QString tgc;
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\234f25fs.default\cookies.sqlite");
bool ok = db.open();
if (!ok)
{
    // qDebug() << "Error: connection with database fail";
}
else
{
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT value WHERE name='TGC' FROM moz_cookies");
    if (query.next())
    {
        tgc = query.value(0).toString();
    }
}
db.close();
return tgc;
```

However, `db.open()` returns false. What are the possible reasons for that?

Comment: Use forward slash `/` instead of backslash or escape your backslash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C and C++, `\` characters are by default used as escape characters, they are used to represent some special characters (like `'\n'` which means the newline character). You need to escape them when you mean to actually use them in a string literal.

So, your `setDatabaseName` call should look something like this:

```
db.setDatabaseName("C:\\Users\\myaccount\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\234f25fs.default\\cookies.sqlite");
```